# How Rails send the parameters in forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an HTML form that works great, it has some sensible data on it, so I would like that only the token parameter goes to my server. It is like this:

```
<form id="payment-form" method="POST">              
            <div class="usable-creditcard-form">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <div class="input-group nmb_a">
                        <div class="icon ccic-brand"><label for="number">Número do Cartão</label></div>
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="credit_card_number" data-iugu="number" placeholder="Número do Cartão" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="six columns">
                    <div class="input-group nmb_b">
                        <div class="icon ccic-cvv"><label for="verification_value">Codigo de Seguranca</label></div>
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="credit_card_cvv" data-iugu="verification_value" placeholder="CVV" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="six columns">
                    <div class="input-group nmb_c">
                        <div class="icon ccic-name"><label for="full_name">Nome Completo</label></div>
                        <input class="credit_card_name" data-iugu="full_name" placeholder="Titular do Cartão" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="six columns">
                         <div class="input-group nmb_d">
                        <div class="icon ccic-exp"><label for="expiration">Data de Expiracao (MM/AA)</label></div>
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="credit_card_expiration" data-iugu="expiration" placeholder="MM/AA" type="text" value="" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="six columns">
                    <div class="token-area">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="" readonly="true" size="64" style="text-align:center" />
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit">Comprar</button>
            </div>
```

But when I use the Form Helpers from Rails, all the parameters are sent to my server, I don`t know why, but I would like that, using the form helpers, only the token field been sent

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_tag iugu_checkout_path, :id=>"payment-form" do%>
   <div class="usable-creditcard-form">
    <div class="input-group nmb_a">
      <div class="icon ccic-brand">
        <%= label_tag :number, "Número do Cartão" %>
      </div>
  <%= text_field_tag :number, nil , :class=> "credit_card_number", "data-iugu"=> "number" %>  
</div>


<%= label_tag :verification_value, "Codigo de Seguranca" %>
<%= text_field_tag :verification_value, nil , :class=> "credit_card_cvv", "data-iugu"=> "verification_value" %>  

<%= label_tag :full_name, "Nome Completo" %>
<%= text_field_tag :full_name, nil , :class=> "credit_card_name", "data-iugu"=> "full_name" %>  

<%= label_tag :expiration, "Data de Expiracao (MM/AA)" %>
<%= text_field_tag :expiration, nil , :class=> "credit_card_expiration", "data-iugu"=> "expiration" %>  

    <%= hidden_field_tag :token%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Comprar" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Why with the HTML form only one parameter goes to my server and with the Form Helpers all the parameters are sent, and how I send only the token parameter using the Form Helpers ?

Comment: If you want to just send the token param then just just keep the token input and display all the other as static text in label instead of text input boxes. Any textfield inside the form will be sent back to the server. So to avoid values being sent to the server, just display them as text and not in input text boxes.

Comment: But the user need to input it! The diference is that the data is handled by JS and this JS (an API) fill the token field for me.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, `text_field_tag` will generate a text field with the name you specified as the first param in `text_field_tag` hence when the form submits, all the textfield with names will be sent with their respective values. While your html form doesn't have name attribute on the text field at all. Thats why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my above comments.

A very quick solution that comes to my mind is that just remove the name attribute from the `text_field_tag` so you get something like this

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="credit_card_number" data-iugu="number" placeholder="Número do Cartão" type="text" value="" />
```

which means, you have to change the text_field_tag to

```
text_field_tag nil, nil , :class=> "credit_card_number", "data-iugu"=> "number"
```

instead of

```
text_field_tag :number, nil , :class=> "credit_card_number", "data-iugu"=> "number"
```

Of course you have to change all the other textfield, the values of which you dont want to be sent.
Hope that helps